# Dependency Property: Getting but not Setting

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SingleGridLengthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SingleGridLength", typeof(double), typeof(MapConverter));

public class MapConverter : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged, IMultiValueConverter
{
    public double SingleGridLength
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MapConverter.SingleGridLengthProperty); }
        set 
        {
            SetValue(MapConverter.SingleGridLengthProperty, value);
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged("SingleGridLength");
        }
    }

<local:MapConverter x:Key="MapConverter"
SingleGridLength="{Binding SingleGridLength, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

I have a converter with a set of dependency properties bound in the .xaml

The problem I am having is each property is "getting" and returning the value but it never "sets" the value. Am I allowed to use dependency properties in converters? Or should I be approaching this a different way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

First, your binding is invalid. You are binding the SingleGridLength property to itself. You would need to bind it to another property/object.

Second, you shouldn't raise the OnNotifyPropertyChanged in the setter for your SingleGridLength property. You only need to do that for regular CLR properties. Dependency properties have a built in change notification system that Binding hooks into.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [PropertyChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx) delegate that you can specify in the [PropertyMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557327.aspx) constructor. The callback will be invoked when the property value of your dependency property changes, and you can place your handling code within this callback method.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a Converter basing on IValueConverter?
The converter then should only do the calculation from the input to the output format. The value returned by the converters

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
```

and

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
```

will be used by the property you did the binding on.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx